# Parsing CSV file with \n in double quoted fields

Tags: bash, groovy

I'm parsing a CSV file that has a break line in double quoted fields. I'm reading the file line by line with a groovy script but I get an ArrayIndexOutBoundException when I tried to get access the missing tokens.

I was trying to pre-process the file to remove those characters and I was thinking to do that with some bash script or with groovy itself.

Could you, please suggest any approach that I can use to resolve the problem?

This is how the CSV looks like:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
timestamp, "abcdefghi", "abcdefghi","sdsd"
timestamp, "zxcvb
fffffgfg","asdasdasadsd","sdsdsd"
```

This is the groovy script I'm using

```
def csv = new File(args[0]).text
def bufferString = ""
def parsedFile = new File("Parsed_" + args[0]);

csv.eachLine { line, lineNumber ->

    def splittedLine = line.split(',');


    retString += new Date(splittedLine[0]) + ",${splittedLine[1]},${splittedLine[2]},${splittedLine[3]}\n";

         if(lineNumber % 1000 == 0){
                parsedFile.append(retString);
                retString = "";
         }

}
parsedFile.append(retString);
```

**UPDATE:**

Finally I did this and it works, (I needed format the first column from timestamp to a human readable date):

```
 gawk -F',' '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr( $1, 0, length($1)-3 ) )","($2)","($3)","($4)}' TobeParsed.csv > Parsed.csv
```

Thank you @karakfa

Comment: You need to post code in a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should probably use a real csv parser

Comment: Yeah, https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv for example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

this will merge the newline split fields together, you process can take it from there

```
$ awk -F'"' '!(NF%2){getline remainder;$0=$0 OFS remainder}1' splitted.csv

header1,header2,header3
xxxxxx, "abcdefghi", "abcdefghi"
yyyyyy, "zxcvb fffffgfg","asdasdasadsd"
```

assumes that odd number of quotes mean split field and replace new line with OFS.  If you want to simple delete new line (the split parts will combine) remove OFS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response!. 

Now I see this is what I needed. With this I can solve my entire problem without make anything else. 

Finally this is what I did and It worked:

`gawk -F',' '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", substr( $1, 0, length($1)-3 ) )","($2)","($3)","($4)}' TobeParsed.csv > Parsed.csv`

I barely undestand awk but it seems its a powerfull language! Thank you very much!

Comment: The script in the answer will fail if/when there are 2 newlines in one field and uses getline incorrectly (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline). The script in the comment is hard-coding commas when setting OFS would be appropriate and using needless parens and seems totally unrelated to your question. @mlavarreda get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Also doesn't handle escaped quotes but may not be important for the OP.  `getline var` usage preserves `$0` and the script doesn't depend on line numbers, so seems a proper use in this case.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a proper CSV parser rather than trying to do it with split (which as you can see doesn't work with any form of quoting), then it works fine:

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.1')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def csv = '''header1,header2,header3,header4
timestamp, "abcdefghi", "abcdefghi","sdsd"
timestamp, "zxcvb
fffffgfg","asdasdasadsd","sdsdsd"'''

def data = parseCsv(csv)
data.eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    println """Line $index:
              |    1:$line.header1
              |    2:$line.header2
              |    3:$line.header3
              |    4:$line.header4""".stripMargin()
}
```

Which prints:

```
Line 0:
    1:timestamp
    2:abcdefghi
    3:abcdefghi
    4:sdsd
Line 1:
    1:timestamp
    2:zxcvb
fffffgfg
    3:asdasdasadsd
    4:sdsdsd
```

Comment: Nothing like using tape to fix the pipes! Good luck!